# css display:block does not work in related articles

Tags: css, wordpress, block, display

I am trying to modify the style of the Contextual Related Posts Plugin for Wordpress. I used this style: http://kevin.deldycke.com/2012/04/beautify-contextual-related-posts-wordpress-plugin/
And by trial and error, made this out of it:

```
.crp_related {
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: block;
}
.crp_related h3 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.crp_related ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    display: block;
}
.crp_related li, .crp_related a {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
.crp_related li {
    margin: 5px !important;
    display: block;
}
.crp_related a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.crp_related .crp_title {
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.crp_related .crp_excerpt {
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    color: #333;
    height: inherit;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.crp_clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

It looks like this: http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2013/09/welkom-bij-meeting-halfway/

This looks already pretty similar to what I want, except that I would like a line break after the title, and, if possible, I'd like the text excerpt clickable as well.

I tried to make the line break with the `display: block;` in various places but nothing works.

Comment: Can you control the markup (HTML) of the plugin?

Comment: Could you please provide the html markup where those classes are being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
Improved my code and works flawlessly for me!

To add a line break you can change your `.crp_related .crp_title` and `.crp_related .crp_excerpt` CSS to this:

```
.crp_related .crp_title {
    color: #000;
    float: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px; /* play with this to add more room under the title */
}

.crp_related .crp_excerpt {
    color: #333;
    height: inherit;
    left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Adding a link to the excerp would mean that you have to change the HTML of the page. You'd have to edit the php files of the plugin.

Comment: I believe the OP doesn't want any text to the right of the title.

Comment: Ah yes, I see my answer doesn't properly work because it's floated. I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. And I can live without a link in the text then.

Comment: Geen probleem, succes met de website! Also, could you mark the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the markup I found in the example you gave, hoping it's the same in your plugin. You just need to add `display:block` and `margin-top: 30px` in `.crp_related .crp_excerpt`.

```css
.crp_related {
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
.crp_related h3 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.crp_related ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: block;
}
.crp_related li,
.crp_related a {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.crp_related li {
  margin: 5px !important;
  display: block;
}
.crp_related a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.crp_related .crp_title {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.crp_related .crp_excerpt {
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  color: #333;
  height: inherit;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}
.crp_clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="crp_related ">
  <h3>Das könnte dir auch gefallen…</h3>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2014/01/15-wensen-voor-2014/">
        <img src="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2014/01/hopes2014featured-150x150.jpg" alt="15 wensen voor 2014" title="15 wensen voor 2014" width="150" height="150" class="crp_thumb crp_featured">
      </a><a href="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2014/01/15-wensen-voor-2014/" class="crp_title">15 wensen voor 2014</a><span class="crp_excerpt"> Dit nieuwe jaar zal een belangrijke zijn voor onze continent, met verkiezingen in het Europees Parlement en het economische crisis nog niet opgelost. 15 leden van het Meeting Halfway team delen hun wensen en verwachtingen voor Europa in 2014.</span>
    </li>
    <hr>
    <li>
      <a href="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2013/10/groot-brittannie-of-klein-brittannie/">
        <img src="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2013/10/20131001-Great-Britain-or-little-Britain-1-Clare-Jordan-photographer-Clare-Jordan-150x150.jpg" alt="Groot-Brittannië of klein Brittannië?" title="Groot-Brittannië of klein Brittannië?"
        width="150" height="150" class="crp_thumb crp_featured">
      </a><a href="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2013/10/groot-brittannie-of-klein-brittannie/" class="crp_title">Groot-Brittannië of klein Brittannië?</a><span class="crp_excerpt"> De Britten zijn berucht voor hun gebrek aan talenkennis. Volgens een gepubliceerde enquête van de British Council is 78% van de Britse bevolking niet in staat om een tweede taal te spreken.</span>
    </li>
    <hr>
    <li>
      <a href="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2013/10/mijn-twee-talen/">
        <img src="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/wp-content/uploads/sites/14/2013/10/20130930-Bilingual-student-1-Eva-Lietavová-@Private-150x150.jpg" alt="Mijn Twee Talen" title="Mijn Twee Talen" width="150" height="150" class="crp_thumb crp_featured">
      </a><a href="http://nl.meetinghalfway.eu/2013/10/mijn-twee-talen/" class="crp_title">Mijn Twee Talen</a><span class="crp_excerpt"> Ze heeft altijd van de Franse taal gehouden. Om deze simpele reden besloot Eva zich op een tweetalige middelbare school in te schrijven. Via deze school ging ze naar de universiteit, waar ze nu Frans studeert. Zo triviaal als het nu misschien lijkt, slechts een paar jaar geleden had Eva geen idee hoe haar leven zou veranderen.</span>
    </li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
  <div class="crp_clear"></div>
</div>
```